# OSM Display a particular changeset-version of a way

Tags: openstreetmap, change-detection

Is it possible to visualize an particular changeset of an way?

It's about this way:

```
http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/24837452
```

At the moment it seems to be a part of an MultiPolygon, but in the past it wasn't. I have an OSM file which is a bit older and contains this version:

```
<way id="24837452" version="64" changeset="13731788" uid="362915" user="micha555" timestamp="2012-11-03T09:11:23Z">
```

Even when the first and last node in this version of the way is the same, mongodb tells me this polygon is invalid. So I would like to visualize it.

If I try to open the history

```
http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/24837452/history
```

I always get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/24837452 (at the bottom) the way is part of a multipolygon relation 1186597. But you will not see that in the history of the way, only in the history of the relation. The way does not necessarily change when it is added to a relation.

The relation was last changed in changeset 17010999. You can use http://osmhv.openstreetmap.de/changeset.jsp?id=17010999
for further investigation on that changeset. The page can be switched to English as well.

http://osmhv.openstreetmap.de/blame.jsp?id=1186597 is another tool for relation history, but that takes quite some time to get the data. If you see nothing, reload after a while.

If you want the full data of a relation with ways and node coordinates, use
http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1186597/full.

You can have the data from version 64 of your way with http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/24837452/64, but there is no option to get the node coordinates of an older version as well.

Comment: hi i already have the data of the changeset, i just want to view the way in this version on the open-streetmap-viewer to see wants wrong with this polygon... do you know any online-polygon-plotting tool where i can import all these points?

Comment: Why don't you use QGIS? It can read complete osm data with `Add Vector Layer`.

Comment: i'll try that.. can it read huge files like 6GB?

Comment: No, that might fail. But you could use ogr2ogr to put the data directly into a spatialite database. Not sure if it handles multipolygons right, osm2pgsql definitely will (with a postgis database).

Comment: ok maybe i can export a smaller file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JOSM [ChangeSet Manager](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Dialog/ChangesetManager) to download a specific Changeset.

```
Open JSOM
Navigate to the area 
Press Ctrl-Alt-C
Enter 13731788 in the Changeset ID; Box and click the button beside it.
Click the Button on the Left hand side under the Query Button (Green Down Arrow) - Download the Content
Click the Bottm Button on the Left Hand Side - Zoom to the Objects
```

The Id Changeset 13731788 is obtained from the History Panel on OSM or you can download Changesets using a Bounding Box by Clicking the Query Button on the Changeset manager

Comment: hi i already have the data of the changeset, i just want to view the way in this version on the open-streetmap-viewer

Answer (score 1):

You can use OSM's [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API). To download the current version of way *24837452* via the API use the URL http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/24837452. It tells you that this way currently has version *65*. To get an older version, just append the version number to the URL. For example, this will get you the previous version *64*: http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/24837452/64

Remember that this API is not suited for bulk-queries.

Comment: hi i already have the data of the changeset, i just want to view the way in this version on the open-streetmap-viewer to see wants wrong with this polygon

Comment: What is *the open-streetmap-viewer*?

Comment: this: http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/24837452 =)

Comment: No, *this* cannot visualize an arbitrary version of a way. Only the latest one is supported, previous versions won't get rendered. But you can visualize an older version by downloading and viewing it using [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/).